# Building a sub-project of a Gradle build, where another sub-project is Android

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Gradle multi-project build where one sub-project is an Android project, and another sub-project is not.  Both rely on a shared project.

Currently it is not possible for me to build the non-Android sub-project in an environment without the Android SDKs installed, because their presence is required for the configuration phase.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.
> failed to find target android-21 : /
```

How can I build this project without requiring Android installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a subproject separately by using its name (usually the directory name) in the build command. For example, if you have these directories:

```
project
    subproject
    subprojectAndroid
```

You can run `gradlew :subproject:build` to tell Gradle to only build the non-Android subproject.